# Why are there multiple virtualenvs in screen?

Tags: python, unix, virtualenv

When I log onto my server, the virtualenv automatically goes to X.

```
(X)[andrew@hyperion ~]$
```

But then when I use `screen`, it changes to

```
(X)(X)[andrew@hyperion ~]$
```

If I then try to change the virtual environment (i.e. `source Y/bin/activate`) I get

```
(Y)(X)[andrew@hyperion ~]$
```

When I try `deactivate` once I get

```
(X)[andrew@hyperion ~]$
```

but the second time, I get an error.  If I then try to change the virtual environment to `Y`, it just goes back to being `(Y)(X)`.

What is going on here?

Comment: What are you executing in (for example) `.bashrc` to start a virtualenv automatically on login?

Comment: source $HOME/virtualenvs/X/bin/active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remote login, bash (or your shell) executes `source $HOME/virtualenvs/X/bin/activate` and modifies `PS1`(the shell prompt) to add the `(X)` prefix.

When you launch screen, a new shell is created which in turn executes `source $HOME/virtualenvs/X/bin/activate`, however for some reason, the existing virtualenv is not available within screen so it creates a new virtualenv and prefixes `PS1` with it's name (also `(X)`), however PS1 already has the (X) prefix at this point, so you see the double (X)(X).

When you manually `source Y/bin/activate`, the existing virtualenv is switched from X inside screen, to Y. So the prompt changes to `(Y)(X)...`.

When you `deactivate`, you jump out of the Y virutalenv, but subsequent `deactivate` commands fail as the initial X virtualenv is outside of the screen shell.

If you then exit screen and `deactivate`, you will jump out of the initial X virtualenv.